# Simple MySQL SELECT/IF, to return if a number is over threshold?

Tags: php, mysql, compare

I am creating a service where a user may only log in 5 times maximum before requiring a new account, how may I verify the count (assuming it is stored in a `tinyint` column named `tries` efficiently without requiring fetching of any columns?

In pseudocode:

```
SELECT FROM table WHERE userid=$uid AND tries <= 5
```

But it appears I need to select something regardless of if I need to return something or not. Is there a way to compare if tries <= 5 without selecting? I wish to rely on mysql_num_rows to check if their account is still valid or not if possible instead of comparing the number in PHP.

Comment: I assume you mean a user may only attempt and fail to log in 5 times.  Generally this shouldn't make them require a new account, it should just lock them out for a period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS answer FROM ...
```

will return minimal info where 0 can be false, >0 true

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ...`